# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, transition, facebook-sdk-4.0

i've got a problem when I trying to call the method to invite Facebook friends to use my app. When I close the `FBSDKAppInviteDialog` I receive the following error:

> Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for
>   < SettingsViewController: 0x14df04e0 >.

This is my code:

```
class SettingsViewController: UITableViewController, SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate {

    //variables

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //code
    }

    //other methods

    func inviteFriends() {
        let content = FBSDKAppInviteContent()
        content.appLinkURL = NSURL(string: "xxxxxxxx")
        content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = NSURL(string:"http://socialvip-app.com/images/share_img.png")
        FBSDKAppInviteDialog.showFromViewController(self, withContent: content, delegate: self)
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let section=indexPath.section
        let row=indexPath.row
        switch section {
        case 0: switch row {
        case 0: inviteFriends()
        case 1: openFacePage()
        case 2:
            giveUsFiveIndicator.startAnimating()
            openStoreProduct()
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        default: break
            }
        case 2: switch row {
        case 0: logout()
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        case 1: deleteAccount()
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        default: break
            }
        default: break
        }
    }
}

extension SettingsViewController:FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate {

    func appInviteDialog(appInviteDialog: FBSDKAppInviteDialog!, didCompleteWithResults results: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    }

    func appInviteDialog(appInviteDialog: FBSDKAppInviteDialog!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you closing the dialogue? I haven't used the FB SDK for a while but I'll try to help if I can. This error generally arises when you call the transition more that once. E.g. you manually close the dialogue with some event, but the delegate also automatically closes it on a very similar event. I.e. both fire at a similar time.

Comment: @Mackey18 i don't close the dialog, How can i do it?

Comment: "When I close the FBSDKAppInviteDialog I receive the following error:" - And the dialogue doesn't even close? Regardless, how are you attempting to close the dialogue?

Comment: @Mackey18 i meant that i don't close it programmatically but i just press the "cancel" button on Facebook Invite dialog.